# Update only non-empty fields | Object spread

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was wondering if there is a one liner is possible for something like

```
        let updatedUser;
        if (firstName) {
            updatedUser = { ...userData, firstName };
        }
        if (lastName) {
            updatedUser = { ...userData, lastName };
        }
        if (password) {
            updatedUser = { ...userData, password };
        }
```

I'm just checking for empty firstName, lastName and so forth. What if I have several fields like this?

So I don't want to update any of my fields with empty values if I write

```
updatedUser = { ...userData, firstName, lastName, password  };
```

Any possible alternative that exists that can tell object spread or anything else to not update if my field is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
const updatedUser = Object.assign({},
     userData,
     firstName && {firstName},
     lastName && {lastName},
     password && {password}
);
```

or similar with object spread syntax:

```
const updatedUser = {
     ...userData,
     ...firstName && {firstName},
     ...lastName && {lastName},
     ...password && {password}
};
```

Falsy values will be ignored and not lead to the creation of any properties.

Comment: Hi Bergi. Long time! That's dope although it seems a hack! Just help me how would be you come up with this answer ? Where you would look for such a thing?

Comment: First is clear but in second with a spread operator. Why are we spreading firstName, lastName and password.   ....These aren't objects...right?

Also why are we putting these properties under {} eg. {firstName}, {lastName} and so forth

Comment: @kushalvm It just came from my knowledge about `Object.assign` and your attempt in the question… Notice that the second works exactly like the first, just with different syntax. If you want it cleaner and more readable, you might use `...(condition ? {property} : null)`

Answer (score 1):

Not really, however you could use a small helper:

```
 const assignDefined = (target, props) =>
   Object.entries(props).forEach(([k, v]) => v && (target[k] = v));
```

That allows you to write:

```
updateUser = assignDefined({...userData}, { firstName, lastName, password });
```

Comment: How's this working under forEach - `([k, v])`. A callback containing not an item but array as first argument having key values. M not sure document says that at MDN. Surprisingly it works and logs key and value pairs.

Comment: @kushalvm thats array destructuring.